# Install XSDK on Fedora java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment

Tags: java, fedora, xilinx

I was trying to install XSDK on fedora 26. But every time when I was trying to do it in root mode. it give me this error message:

`

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Xilinx Installer.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
ERROR: Installer could not be started. Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:475)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:495)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at i.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.xilinx.installer.gui.E.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.xilinx.installer.gui.InstallerGUI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.xilinx.installer.gui.InstallerGUI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.xilinx.installer.api.InstallerLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

`

I check the DISPLAY it set same as user. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You have probably Wayland and Java does not know how to talk with that. Try to log in with standard  X

Comment: Under Wayland there is still the XWayland server, so that shouldn't be it.

Comment: _But_ under Wayland you can't launch apps as root from the console. Do you need to run this as root?

Comment: Thanks Jakuje! I just used xhost +local:, it works now.